# Satellite imagery dataset containing labels like building footprints or soil type

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, aerial-photography

I'm working on a computer vision project involving satellite/aerial imagery, and I'm having trouble finding the kind of labelled data I need. So far, I've come across datasets like:

- https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Statlog+(Landsat+Satellite)
- https://aws.amazon.com/public-data-sets/spacenet/
- ... (can't post more links)

which contain labels like building footprints or soil type. I'm looking for data that's annotated with features like rivers, forests, deserts, lakes, stuff like that. I'm not sure this is out there, but thought I would ask. Thanks!

Comment: Need to give more elaborate here I am not sure what you were trying to search for ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you aren't just looking for satellite imagery but also feature data sets. Satellite imagery is really great for determining variables based on rad bands but getting down to the level of detail required for building footprints is beyond the scope of most (openly accessible) radar systems.

I'll point here to a few major resources for geospatial data that you'll probably find useful for classifying areas/landforms:

Aerial imagery: [USGS EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/)

Soil types, classifications, characteristics: [ISRIC Soilgrids 250m](https://www.soilgrids.org/)

Land Cover: [ESA GLOBCOVER 2009](http://due.esrin.esa.int/page_globcover.php)

Lakes, Rivers, Watersheds: [WWF/USGS HydroSHEDS](http://hydrosheds.org/)

Comment: If you're interested in contributing to the RS/Aerial Photography community, consider committing to the Stackexchange for it: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90327/remote-sensing-and-photogrammetry?referrer=sDadpSECL0zo9RoVf1VtPg2